# Why is my Code not working? - Responsive Tabs CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to create Tabs which are draggable / swipeable on mobile.

This is what ive got so far but the code does not work..

Even though its not working, i dont think that the code is too far off..

I assume it could be fixed without too much effort.

Any help is much appreciated

```js
const btn = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('button'));
btn.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.addEventListener('click',function(){
    btn.forEach((item) => {item.classList.remove('active')})
    item.classList.add('active')
    document.getElementById('tab').setAttribute('data-tab', index)
  });
});

// detect touch events
if (document.ontouchstart !== null) {
  // register touch events
  document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);
  document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);
}

// handle touch start event
function handleTouchStart(event) {
  // get the touch event object
  const touch = event.touches[0];
  // store the starting position of the touch
  touchStartX = touch.pageX;
}

// handle touch move event
function handleTouchMove(event) {
  // get the touch event object
  const touch = event.touches[0];
  // store the current position of the touch
  touchEndX = touch.pageX;

  // calculate the difference between the starting and current positions of the touch
  const diffX = touchStartX - touchEndX;

  // if the touch moved more than 50 pixels to the left,
  // set the data-tab attribute to the next tab
  if (diffX > 50) {
    const currentTab = document.getElementById('tab').getAttribute('data-tab');
    const nextTab = parseInt(currentTab) + 1;
    document.getElementById('tab').setAttribute('data-tab', nextTab);
  }

  // if the touch moved more than 50 pixels to the right,
  // set the data-tab attribute to the previous tab
  if (diffX < -50) {
    const currentTab = document.getElementById('tab').getAttribute('data-tab');
    const nextTab = parseInt(currentTab) - 1;
    document.getElementById('tab').setAttribute('data-tab', nextTab);
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tabs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .9s ease-in-out; 
  -moz-transition: all .9s ease-in-out; 
  -ms-transition: all .9s ease-in-out; 
  -o-transition: all .9s ease-in-out; 
  transition: all .9s ease-in-out;
}

.tabs> * {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute
}

.tabs[data-tab='1'] {
    left: 0%;
}

.tabs[data-tab='2'] {
    left: -100%
}

.tabs[data-tab='3'] {
    left: -200%
}

.tabs[data-tab='4'] {
    left: -300%
}

.inliner {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.inliner > * {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <button> Tab 1</button>
      <button> Tab 2</button>
      <button> Tab 3</button>
    <div id="tab" class="tabs inliner">
        <div>
            <h2>Content 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Content 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2>Content 3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried around with a lot of CSS,

without success unfortunately

Comment: `This is what ive got so far but the code does not work..` - errors in console? Errors showing in IDE? - we need details please :)

Comment: Im using JSfiddle and other online 'consoles' to display my code since im usually working with simple html/css.
No error output there, sorry. @CanO'Spam

Comment: JSFiddle has a console that shows errors